# munmap() not working when called from function

Tags: c, posix, valgrind

Im writing a library of functions that works with shared memory. The function I am writing to close the shared memory gives me a segfault whenever it gets to the munmap() part, but if i dont use the function and just let the code munmap() and shm_unlink at the end, it works. im very confused as to why. the code is below.

```c
void close_table(table_t *tbl, char* name){
  size_t size = sizeof(tbl->table_size);
  printf("table_size: %d\n", tbl->table_size);
  /* when the first part of if else statement runs its fine */
  if(tbl->numP > 1){
    printf("first if statement\n");
    tbl->numP -= 1;
    munmap(tbl, tbl->table_size);
  }
  /* when second part runs gives seg fault */
  else{
    tbl->numP -= 1;
    munmap(tbl, tbl->table_size);
    //close(tbl->shm_fd);
    shm_unlink(tbl->name);
  }
  // Code omission
}
```

This is the open table function

```
table_t *open_table(char *name, int record_size, int max_records){

  int shm_fd;
  int table_size;
  void* ptr;
  table_t* tbl;
  table_t controlBlock;
  db_info info;
  data_block data;

  table_size = max_records * sizeof(controlBlock) * sizeof(info) *
    sizeof(data);



  if((shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666)) == -1){
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  ftruncate(shm_fd, table_size);
  ptr = mmap(NULL, table_size, PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 
  0);
  tbl = ptr;
  tbl->shm_fd = shm_fd;
  tbl->table_size = table_size;
  tbl->max_records = max_records;
  tbl->record_size = record_size;
  if(tbl->numP >= 1){
    tbl->numP += 1;
  }
  else{
    tbl->numP = 1;
  }

  return tbl;
}
```

these are my structs

```
typedef struct{
  int dbInfoId;
  int deleted;
}db_info;

typedef struct{
  int shm_fd;
  int numP;
  int control_id;
  char *name;
  int table_size;
  int record_size;
  int max_records;
  db_info* dbInfo;
  void* db;
}table_t;


typedef struct{
  int id;
  void* record;
}data_block;
```

valgrind says its an "invalid read of size 8

```
enter a command (just the number):
1. Add
2. Delete
3. Process
4. Close
5. # of processes
6. exit
4
table_size: 29360128
==6679== Invalid read of size 8
==6679==    at 0x108C42: close_table (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==6679==    by 0x108F15: main (main.c:40)
==6679==  Address 0x5654010 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==6679== 
==6679== 
==6679== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==6679==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x5654010
==6679==    at 0x108C42: close_table (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==6679==    by 0x108F15: main (main.c:40)
==6679==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==6679==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==6679==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==6679==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==6679==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
--6679-- REDIR: 0x50db950 (libc.so.6:free) redirected to 0x4c30cd0 (free)
==6679== 
==6679== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6679==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6679==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 2,048 bytes allocated
==6679== 
==6679== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6679== 
==6679== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==6679== 
==6679== 1 errors in context 1 of 1:
==6679== Invalid read of size 8
==6679==    at 0x108C42: close_table (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==6679==    by 0x108F15: main (main.c:40)
==6679==  Address 0x5654010 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==6679== 
==6679== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Do you have other threads still accessing the memory?  Normally when it is an invalid read of 8, it is a pointer.

Comment: There's not enough code here to say for sure, but if memory starting at `tbl` was unmapped, it's very likely invalid to use `tbl->name`.

Comment: Can you provide the code of `table_t` structure?

Comment: @cup whenever that else statement runs, it means its the last process accessing the shared memory. if there are more than one process open aand i try to close the table for a process, the if statement runs to only unmap for that process. I will post the code of the process.

Comment: Try to run your program in GDB, the execution flow will jump in the debugger when the signal happens. You'll be able to see what's what with those variables, as @aschepler said, most likely an invalid access from somewhere.

Comment: I've tried that, but it only points the line in the main where the function is being called, and I already know its the function causing it, just not sure WHAT in the function is causing it.

Comment: Was the `close_table` function compiled with debug info enabled?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it the answer. It turns out I was still trying to access variables in the `tbl` struct after it was unmapped. so to fix this I just created variabbles in the function and saved what I needed from the `tbl` struct before unmapping.

```
void close_table(table_t *tbl){
  int size = tbl->table_size;
  char* name = tbl->name;
  int fd = tbl->shm_fd;
  printf("table_size: %d\n", tbl->table_size);
  if(tbl->numP > 1){
    tbl->numP -= 1;
    munmap(tbl, tbl->table_size);
    close(fd);
  }
  else if(tbl->numP == 1){
    tbl->numP -= 1;
    munmap(tbl, size);
    printf("unmap works\n"); fflush(stdout);
    shm_unlink(name);
    close(fd);
  }
```